# Django library Unresolved Import LiClipse

Tags: python, django, liclipse

I am creating my first Django project from docs.djangoproject.com. After completing tutorial 4, I tried to import my project in LiClipse. But LiClipse is showing error of Unresolved Import however my projects works perfectly fine.
I have added django in external library.
Please help me with this issue.
LiClipse shows error only with django libraries and not with any other python library

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding django package as external library, add the containing folder of django. For example if folder hierarchy is something like /site-package/django than add site-package as external library and not django.